# HeatmapTileProvider with 0 DataPoints

Tags: android, maps, heatmap

I am trying to toggle a heatmap on and off using Android.
I have two lists say:

```
List<LatLng> a = new ArrayList<>
List<LatLng> b = new ArrayList<>

a.add(new LatLng(53.457131,-1.054688);
a.add(new LatLng(53.036407,-4.570313);
a.add(new LatLng(52.182504, -1.054688);

b.add(new LatLng(45.238325,2.460938);
```

I combine these two lists:

```
finalList.addAll(a);
finalList.addAll(b);
```

I want to toggle these lists in the TileOverlay.

```
    aButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (overlay.isVisible()) {
                finalList.removeAll(a);
            } else {
                finalList.addAll(a);
            }
            providor.setData(a);
            overlay.clearTileCache();
        }
```

and I do the same to the second button.

But once you remove both lists (so finalList is empty) I get the following error:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No input points

I would like to know if there is a easy way to implement this.

I have tried to implement this meathod:
On button click check if `finalList.isEmpty()` and remove the overlay if it is.
But then that brings its own problems as then I would have to create new overlay.

I also tried to set the overlay to visible but then that messes up the buttonClick Listener as it checks for `overlay.isVisible()`

Thanks